# How to loop a text based game depending on input in python

Tags: python, loops, text

I have this so far:

```
print('a skeleton comes into view, the hiker must have been dehydrated.')
print ('he was wearing a Yankees HAT, to the right of his body he set his BACKPACK         and WOODEN WALKING STICK next to the wall')
input2 = raw_input ("You may SEARCH____(object),PICK UP____, USE____ ON_____, or GO ON: ")
if input2 == 'PICK UP HAT':
    print 'taken'
    hat = hat+1
    input2 = raw_input ("You may SEARCH____(object),PICK UP____, USE____ ON_____, or GO ON: ")
#
#
#

if input2 == 'SEARCH BACKPACK':
    print ("there are OLD CLOTHES in here as well as a TARP")
    input2 = raw_input ("You may SEARCH____(object),PICK UP____, USE____ ON_____, or GO ON: ")


elif input2 == 'PICK UP CLOTHES':
    print ("tsken")
    input2 = raw_input ("You may SEARCH____(object),PICK UP____, USE____ ON_____, or GO ON: ")


elif input2 == 'PICK UP TARP':
    print ("taken")
    input2 = raw_input ("You may SEARCH____(object),PICK UP____, USE____ ON_____, or GO ON: ")


elif input2 == 'PICK UP BONE':
    print ("taken")
    input2 = raw_input ("You may SEARCH____(object),PICK UP____, USE____ ON_____, or GO ON: ")


elif input2 == 'PICK UP WOODEN WALKING STICK':
    print "Taken"
    input2 = raw_input ("You may SEARCH____(object),PICK UP____, USE____ ON_____, or GO ON: ")


elif input2 == 'GO ON':
    input3 = raw_input ("left or right: ")
    if input3 == 'left':
        import module3
    elif input3 == 'right':
        import module4
```

I am having trouble understanding if I should create a while or for statement here.

For example: how do I make it so that the person playing the game cannot pick up a hat twice or pick up the tarp without searching the back pack.

Comment: For future posts on SO, you may want to take a look at [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186). I cleaned up your code indentation as best as I could.

Answer (score 1):

A solution for part of your problem is to use a dispatcher:

```
def pick_up_hat():
  return True # do stuff

def search_backpack():
  return False # do stuff

actions = {
  'PICK UP HAT': pick_up_hat,
  'SEARCH BACKPACK': search_backpack,
  # ...
}

go = True
while go:
  cmd = raw_input().strip()
  go = actions[cmd]()
```

Note that there are some other problems with your design that you will need to fix, like managing state.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the cmd module, which is part of the standard library. It provides convenient infrastructure for implementing terminal based command parsing, menus and such. Here's a good basic tutorial:

http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/cmd/index.html

There's also a drop-in replacement third party module called cmd2 that works the same way but has more features:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cmd2